# Add date change script

Tags: javascript, date

I have this code that shows the date of the next day. Is it possible to change the behavior of the dates so it changes at 17:00? For example, now the code shows the date 16.6.2020 (this is correct), and after 17:00, it should show 17.6.2020

```js
document.querySelector("a[href='data']").setAttribute("id", "day");
document.querySelector("a[href='data2']").setAttribute("id", "day2");

var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = day + "." + month + "." + year;
document.getElementById("day2").innerHTML = day + "." + month + "." + year;
```

```html
<a class="tn-atom" href="data" id=""></a>
<a class="tn-atom" href="data2" id=""></a>
```

Comment: Well, nothing is checking whether the time is before or after 17:00...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this (comment currentDate.setHours(18) after test)

```js
const pad = num => ("0"+num).slice(-2)
document.querySelector("a[href='data']").setAttribute("id", "day");
document.querySelector("a[href='data2']").setAttribute("id", "day2");

var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
currentDate.setHours(18); // comment this when tested
if (currentDate.getHours() >=17) currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1)
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var year = currentDate.getFullYear()

document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = pad(day) + "." + pad(month) + "." + year;
document.getElementById("day2").innerHTML = pad(day) + "." + pad(month) + "." + year;
```

```html
<a class="tn-atom" href="data" id=""></a>
<a class="tn-atom" href="data2" id=""></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel like messing with time zones, add 7 hours to the date for it to show the next days date at 17:00

```js
var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 31 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
console.log(currentDate)

// testing DST
const aroundDST = new Date(2020,2,29,0,0,0,0); // 29th of March 2020 - DST-SST in most of Europe
const afterDST = new Date(aroundDST.getTime() + 31 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
console.log(afterDST)
```

Comment: Hmm, seems like a cool trick. Will it work across DST?

Comment: It should as long as the clients time is adjusted accordingly